# Medir tiempo de ejecución en multiples funciones Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo multiples funciones en las que ocupo medir cuanto tarda en correr cada función, he encontrado ejemplos utiles cómo el de usar una clase para eso:

```
class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._start_time = None

    def start(self):
        self._start_time = time.perf_counter()

    def stop(self):
        elapsed_time = time.perf_counter() - self._start_time
        self._start_time = None
        print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time:0.4f} seconds")
```

La forma en que utilizo en mis funciones es algo así:

```
    t = Timer()


    def create_data(args):
        with transaction.manager:
             t.start()
             msp = msp_automation()
             t.stop()
```

Este método me sirve para lo que busco pero el problema es que tengo mas de 50 funciones que ocupo medir cuanto tardan entonces el usar `t.start()` y `t.stop()` en cada función no parece lo más conveniente , alguna recomendación para saber qué utilizar? cualquier recomendación se agradece

Comment: Utiliza un decorador

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Otra opción aparte del decorador que comentó Christian es utilizar el módulo [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Puedes configurar rangos de prueba, por ejemplo para proporcionar diferentes valores de entrada a las funciones entre otras opciones bastante útiles.

Ejemplo con dos funciones sencillas y midiendo su tiempo de ejecución y te permite configurar el número de ejecuciones que quieres calcular (En este caso 500), te recomiendo revisar la documentación completa.

```
import timeit
    
def suma(*args):
    return sum(args)

def potencia(a,b):
    return a**b

print(timeit.timeit('suma(*range(100))', setup="from __main__ import suma", number = 500))
print(timeit.timeit('(potencia(a,2) for a in range(3))', setup="from __main__ import potencia", number = 500))
```

Comment: muchas gracias @HeytalePazguato , utilicé el decorador mencionado por Christian